# How to add title above a table?

Tags: tables, titles

I am trying to add a title above a table, without success. Here the code:

```
    \begin{table}[b]
      \centering
      \begin{tabular}{|c|c|c|c|}
      \cline{2-4}
      \multicolumn{1}{c|}{}& &{CPU time}&\\
      \cline{2-4}
      \multicolumn{1}{c|}{} & Algorithm 1  & Algorithm 2  & Algorithm 3\\
      \hline
      $n=29$                & $0.001137$   & $0.000962$   & $0.000679$\\
      \hline
      $n=97$                & $0.020917$   & $0.008182$   & $0.005571$\\
      \hline
      $n=353$               & $0.699906$   & $0.067613$   & $0.054980$\\
      \hline
      $n=1345$              & $32.03852$   & $1.063334$   & $0.823744$\\
      \hline
    \end{tabular}
    \caption{Caption}
    \label{time}
    \end{table}
```

[image]

How to have a better setting of title? Thanks!

What I would like to obtain is this:

[image]

Comment: By default, the `\caption` just appears where you put it, so if you want it before the tabular rather than after, put it there.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. However, by title I mean 'CPU time' and not the caption.

Comment: @Mik What do you mean exactly? Now you put `CPU time` in a cell of the table.

Comment: What does it mean for you to "successfully" add the title? With your current code you have added the `CPU time` title, but presumably you don't like the way that it appears. It would help if you said how you wanted to add the title.

Comment: Thanks for your suggest. Actually, I did explain what I would obtain. I am going to modify my question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An alternative layout without vertical lines and with aligned decimal separators could be

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage[a4paper]{geometry}
\usepackage{booktabs,siunitx}
\begin{document}
\begin{table}[b]
\centering
\begin{tabular}{l S S S S }
\toprule
\multicolumn{1}{c}{} &     \multicolumn{3}{c}{\large CPU Time}          \\
                            & \multicolumn{1}{c}{Algorithm 1}  & \multicolumn{1}{c}{Algorithm 2}  & \multicolumn{1}{c}{Algorithm 3}\\
      \midrule
      $n=29$                & 0.001137   & 0.000962   & 0.000679 \\
      \midrule
      $n=97$                & 0.020917   & 0.008182   & 0.005571  \\
      \midrule
      $n=353$               & 0.699906   & 0.067613   & 0.054980  \\
      \midrule
      $n=1345$              & 32.03852   & 1.063334  & 0.823744  \\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}
\caption{Caption\label{time}}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

using the `siunitx` and the `booktabs` packages

[image]

Answer (score 3):

OK, you could do this

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage[a4paper]{geometry}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\begin{document}
    \begin{table}[b]
      \centering
      \begin{tabular}{|c|c|c|c|}
      \cline{2-4}
      \multicolumn{1}{c}{}  & \multicolumn{3}{|c|}{CPU time}\\
      \cline{2-4}
      \multicolumn{1}{c|}{} & Algorithm 1  & Algorithm 2  & Algorithm 3\\
      \hline
      $n=29$                & $0.001137$   & $0.000962$   & $0.000679$\\
      \hline
      $n=97$                & $0.020917$   & $0.008182$   & $0.005571$\\
      \hline
      $n=353$               & $0.699906$   & $0.067613$   & $0.054980$\\
      \hline
      $n=1345$              & $32.03852$   & $1.063334$   & $0.823744$\\
      \hline
    \end{tabular}
    \caption{Caption}
    \label{time}
    \end{table}
\end{document}
```

but the layout seems ugly. Avoid vertical lines in tables.

[image]

Comment: Also, you might consider aligning the decimal separators.

Comment: Thanks for your suggest. How to do that? And how to have a more beautiful layout?